# $(X \times X) /{\sim'}\cong (X/{\sim}) \times (X/{\sim})$

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

The full description of this problem is:

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $\sim'$ be the equivalence relation on $X\times X$ defined by $(x,y)\sim'(x',y')$ iff $x \sim x'$ and $y \sim y'$
>
> Prove that $(X \times X) /{\sim'}\,\cong (X/{\sim}) \times (X/{\sim})$.

Intuitively it makes so much sense, but I am really stuck on how to write a formal proof. Can anyone give me a outline?

Great thanks!

Comment: What is $X$? Just a set? What does it mean $\cong$?

Comment: Respectively: a topological space, no, and homeomorphic @JonSK

Comment: X is a topological space and $\cong$ stands for homeomorphic. I ll edit it now

Comment: I don't think this is true in general...it's definitely not true in general if you let the two factors be different spaces.

Comment: @EricWofsey Shall the quotient map $\pi: X \to X /\sim $ be open?

Comment: Yes, that would make it true.

Comment: @EricWofsey May you briefly explain the difference?

Comment: For counterexamples to the general claim, you can see the answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958372/product-of-quotient-maps-and-quotient-space-that-is-not-hausdorff.  (Strictly speaking, they are only examples of where the canonical bijection fails to be a homeomorphism; to prove that there is no bijection at all would take more work.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Thx!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The homeomorphism is given by
$$f:(X\times X)/{{\sim}'}\longrightarrow (X/{\sim})\times (X/{\sim})$$
defined by $$f([(x,y)])=([x],[y]).$$

Prove it !

Comment: Protip (that I just searched on TeX.se for because it was driving me nuts!), it turns out enclosing `\sim` in braces makes it play a bit more nicely with the slash; e.g., $X/{\sim}$ vs $X/\sim$ or $X/_\sim$

Comment: Thanks a lot!. It is clearly bijective, but how to show it is continuous? Is it supposed to use the definition of open sets of quotient space?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** -

Using the [universal property of quotient spaces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Properties) you can get a continuous map $\phi:(X\times X)/ {\sim'}\to X/ {\sim}\times X/ {\sim}$ which in this case you can show to be bijective and open.

Comment: Thanks! Is my idea correct? since $\pi \times \pi: X \times X \to (X/\sim)\times (X/\sim)$ is a quotient map, then by the universal property, there exists such $\phi$? And then show it is bijective and open.

Comment: @Xuan, absolutely! you are right

Comment: You can't easily show $\phi$ is open, since it isn't in general.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, I didn't mean that it was true in general. I meant it for this problem. I shall remove the word "easily" in my answer at it depends on person to person.