# Proof of “The product of two quotient maps need not be a quotient map”

Tags: general-topology

Problem: The product of two quotient maps need not be a quotient map

I started proof by followings

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and let $X^*$ (obtained from $X$) be the set identifying the subset $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to $a$ point $b$
And let $\mathbb{Q}$ be rational numbers

Claim :
1)  $p$: $X\to X^*$ be the quotient map. 
2)  $q$: $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ be identity map then $q$ is quotient map
3)  $p\times q$: $X\times \mathbb{Q}\to X^*\times\mathbb{Q}$ is not quotient map

I want to know how to prove $1$, $2$, and $3$
In particular, why $p$ is surjective

Comment: $p$ is surjective because we define it so, as equivalence classes. Given any surjective function from a topological space $X$ to a set $Y$, we can equip $Y$ with a topology so that the function is a quotient map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Product of quotient maps and quotient space that is not Hausdorff](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958372/product-of-quotient-maps-and-quotient-space-that-is-not-hausdorff?rq=1)

Comment: 1 and 2 are trivial: 1 is about the canonical quotient map for an equivalence relation, which is always surjective and is defined to be quotient. 2: the identity map is always a quotient map, as are all homeomorphisms.